# How do I render a list item differently on the last item?

Tags: asp.net, razor, foreach, umbraco

I am trying to make a menu that will appear like this:

LOGS | BULLETIN | LOCATIONS | DIRECTORY | POLICIES

Note that the last item does not have a | after it.

This is my code now:

```
    <ul>
        @{
            var homeNode = Model.Content.AncestorOrSelf("Homepage");
        }
        @foreach (var node in homeNode.Children.Where("Visible"))
        {
            <li>
                <a href="@node.Url">@node.AsDynamic().Name</a> |
            </li>
        }
    </ul>
```

Which renders this:

LOGS | BULLETIN | LOCATIONS | DIRECTORY | POLICIES |

What can I add to the code so that it adds | after each node name EXCEPT the last one?

Comment: If you use a `for` loop instead of `foreach` you'll be able to tell when you're on the last record in the collection you iterate over.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This should work:

```
var homeNode = Model.Content.AncestorOrSelf("Homepage");

var nodes = homeNode.Children.Where("Visible");

foreach (var node in nodes)
{
    <li>
        <a href="@node.Url">@node.Name</a> 
        @if (node != nodes.Last())
        {
            @Html.Raw("&nbsp;|&nbsp")
        }
    </li>
}
```

Wing

Comment: I'm going to try this out. Thanks!